# Popup window works in React dev server but not prod build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

This might be a dumb question, I'm still new to React.

This is a reproducible example of my app. Using the dev server this works fine, but in the prod build, I just get a 404 when the popup comes up.

It also doesn't work in the sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-leftpad-gidhvf

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("main"));

function Main() {
  return (
    <>
      <Link
        onClick={() => {
          window.open("/popup", "popup", "width=500,height=500");
        }}
      >
        <p>Click me to open popup</p>
      </Link>
      //this is where other static content could go
    </>
  );
}

function Popup() {
  return <>This is what's in the popup</>;
}

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/*" index element={<Main />}></Route>
        <Route path="/popup" index element={<Popup />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

When running the build, it's clearly looking for an index file in the `/popup` directory instead of running the element component associated with the route. If there is no `/popup` directory, and no `index.html` inside, the resulting popup window throws a 404. If I create that directory and root file, it throws a 403.

Comment: It does not give any error in my case.

Comment: In the sandbox or in a dev server?

Comment: I just run it in your sandbox.

Comment: But the popup comes up blank in the sandbox. It should say "This is what's in the popup". In a build, it throws a 404

Comment: If you type ‘popup’ in the embedded browser url in sandbox, it is working. This means there is a problem with server level redirecting. This is why it works on your local and not production.

Comment: @SedatPolat yes I think you're correct. I added a location directive in the nginx server block for '/popup' and it now properly renders the '<Popup />' component. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I check the code in sandbox, it looks ok.
Only reason could be `redirecting /popup` url to incorrect server. It will work on local, because every request to localhost:xxxx will go to correct server without needing any redirection config(of course if you do not have any releated redirecting config in the host file).

Note: if you have a react routing in single page reactjs app(url is not opening in new tab/window), redirection will seems like still working as expected even if there is a wrong redirect url config in your server. The reason is, react routing will handle this url path. But if you hard refresh the page or open the page in new tab/window, then request to that url will not reach to the server that react runs on.